# Spark Scala dataframe division and IF

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to avoid division by zero in this calculation (value-(mean/stddev)

This is what I came up with:

```
%sql 
select id,cykle,
s2-(a2/IF(sd2 == 0.0, 0.00000001, sd2)) as std2,
s3-(a3/IF(sd3 == 0.0, 0.00000001, sd3)) as std3,
s4-(a4/IF(sd4 == 0.0, 0.00000001, sd4)) as std4
from XXX where id = 1 order by cykle
```

Two questions
- better way? 
- can I use division and IF in scala code this does not work :

```
($"s1" -  ("$a1"  / IF("$sd1"  == lit(0.0),lit(0.00000001),"$sd1"))).as("std1")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either `coalesce`:

```sql
COALESCE(a2 / sd, a2 / 0.00000001)
```

```scala
val c: Double = ???
coalesce($"a2" / $"sd", $"a2" / lit(c))
```

or use `CASE` ... `WHEN` construct:

```sql
CASE sd
    WHEN 0 THEN a2 / 0.00000001
    ELSE a2 / sd
END
```

```scala
when($"sd" === 0, $"a2" / lit(c)).otherwise($"a2" / $"sd")
```

although if your goal is scaling then keeping defaulting to 0 would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following form more compact:

```
select(..., 'a2 / coalesce('sd, lit(c)), ...)
```